# await seems to block on asycio.Future

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, future

I'm trying to understand python async/await and using `Future` objects to indicate that a function can continue. This is some code that reproduces the problem I am having:

```
import time, threading, asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
f = loop.create_future()

def resolve(fut):
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    fut.set_result(88)

async def wait_on_future(fut):
    print('waiting for fut')
    await fut
    print('done', fut.result())
    return fut.result()

threading.Thread(target=resolve, args=(f,)).start()
loop.create_task(wait_on_future(f))
loop.run_forever()
```

which prints:

```
0
waiting for fut
1
2
```

Note that it never prints `'done'`. In the [awaitables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) section of the docs, it says:

> When a Future object is awaited it means that the coroutine will wait until the Future is resolved in some other place.

I thought that calling `set_result` was the way to resolve a `Future`. What am I missing here?

Note: if I call resolve in the same thread, this works fine. The actual problem I'm trying to solve is that the event that happens to resolve the `Future` is in a thread. I did notice that the [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#future-object) docs say that it is not thread safe. How do you make an async function that awaits an event that happens in another thread?

Comment: "> I did notice that the Future docs say that it is not thread safe."

Most of asyncio isn't thread safe. It often doesn't make sense to use both asyncio and threads. Did you try using multiprocessing instead?

Comment: @CharmingRobot The threads are originating in a C++ code wrapped with cython. I'm trying to use the callbacks fired by those threads to resolve Futures in some async code. I'm familiar with multiprocessing;  it does not help resolve this problem, but thank you for the thought.

Comment: Did you take a look at the `run_in_executor` asyncio function? maybe you can call `await run_in_executor(resolve(f)) from within your coroutine?

Comment: Also if you want to schedule a coroutine on a different thread, you can use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` .
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe

Comment: @CharmingRobot I think `run_coroutine_threadsafe` may work for me, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @CharmingRobot's comment about `run_coroutine_threadsafe`, I came to this solution:

```
import time, threading, asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
f = loop.create_future()

def resolve(fut):
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    async def a_resolve():
        fut.set_result(88)
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(a_resolve(), loop)

async def wait_on_future(fut):
    print('waiting for fut')
    return await fut

async def print_future():
    print('got the future! value:', await wait_on_future(f))

loop.create_task(print_future())
threading.Thread(target=resolve, args=(f,)).start()
loop.run_forever()
```

which prints:

```
0
waiting for fut
1
2
got the future! value: 88
```

which is what I was looking for.